# How to Handle UnhandledAlertException and then continue execution

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am facing an `UnhandledAlertException` in my application.
What I want to do is :

1. Handle the exception.
2. Refresh the page.
3. Continue my execution.

If any suggestions, please help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code

```
        try{
                    Alert alert = driver.switchTo().alert();
                    alert.accept();
            }
            catch(NoAlertPresentException e)
            {
                    //
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

With the amount of information specified I can only advise you to not `throw` the exception but instead of that use a `try/catch` block and try to handle it there.

```
try{
    // do your stuff
}catch(Exception e){
    System.out.print("Exception caught: " + e);
}
```

However if the execution of the faulty part of the code is neccessary for the continuation you won't be able to do so, unless you provide compensatory data.

Edit:

My point was to supplement the missing data so if you're doing something like this in the try block: `String foo = webService.getData();` then the catch block should provide something for foo if it's neccessary for continuation.. So in the catch block:

```
System.out.println("Exception: " + e); 
String foo = "something";
```

**But I presume you're doing Selenium tests so if it's throwing errors then it's bad and trying to "find a way around it" is defying it's very purpose.**

Comment: That's what i am doing. I am using a try/catch/finally block, but even the exception is not thrown, it is executing that function (in the finally block) again, as a result it is going in an infinite loop..

Comment: This is because finally block will always execute when try block exits.